# PHP unable to move uploaded file

Tags: php, upload, ffmpeg

I have been trying to create an upload.php script however the condition doesn't seem to work and PHP can not move the uploaded file to the folder upload.

Apache2 log output below

```
PHP Warning:  move_uploaded_file(): The second argument to copy() function cannot be a directory in /var/www/html/upload.php on line 18, referer: http://192.168.0.110/stream.php

PHP Warning:  move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/tmp/phpC34Agu' to '/var/www/html/upload/' in /var/www/html/upload.php on line 18, referer: http://192.168.0.110/stream.php
```

Upload.php code

```
   <?php
$target_path = "/var/www/html/upload/";
$target = $target_path . basename($_FILES['uploadedfile']['name'][0] );
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'] [0], $target_path))
     { 
    echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['uploadefile']['name'] [0]). " has been uploaded"; 
   } 
    else {
 echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file."; 
     }
   ?>
```

I would also like php to execute this ffmpeg command directly afterwards, but i'm unsure where to insert it.

FFMPEG command

```
ffmpeg -re -i uploadedfile.name -vcodec copy -f mpegts udp://239.1.1.1:5000
```

Thanks for all your help.

Kind Regards,

Mark Couto

Comment: what does `print_r($_FILES['fileToUpload'])` return...

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response.
what remove     $target . basename on line three ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the **INDEX KEY of the file**:

$_FILES['uploaded']['tmp_name']**[0]**

```
$target = $target . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"][0]);
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded']['tmp_name'][0], $target))
{ 
    echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name'][0]). " has been uploaded"; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the part of code where the problem is

> ```
>       if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded']['tmp_name'], $target))
> ```

**$_FILES['uploaded']** should be $_FILES[ **'FileToUpload'** ]

Try this

> ```
>       if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['FileToUpload']['tmp_name'], $target))
> ```

<=
http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php

Comment: Thanks Guys,
executed both solutions still an issue in the upload. However i now get a different message                   
                                                                                                                             'Undefined variable: uploaded_size in /var/www/html/upload.php on line 6, referer: http://192.168.0.110/stream.php
  Undefined variable: uploaded_type in /var/www/html/upload.php on line 13, referer: http://192.168.0.110/stream.php'

Any idea? do i have to list them at the top of the script ?

Comment: I also changed the html form to represent the 'filetoupload'

<input name="FileToUpload" type="file" /><br />

Comment: @Markjose what exectly is the issue now?

Comment: Well, the file still won't upload, I am seeing in the apache error log " Underfined variable: Upload_type and size".  Therefore do i need to specify the variables at the top of the script ?

Comment: @Markjose  Variable $uploaded_size is still undefined,  you can define it like this: $uploaded_size=$_FILES["FileToUpload"]["size"];

Comment: @Markjose  Variable **$uploaded_type** is also undefined,  you can define it like this: $uploaded_size=$_FILES["FileToUpload"]["type"]; <=

Comment: Ok, So added both to the top of my page like this:                                                                          
`$target = "/var/www/html/upload/";
 $target = $target . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"][0] );
 $uploaded_size=$_FILES["FileToUpload"]["size"];
 $uploaded_type=$_FILES["FileToUpload"]["type"];`

However still the same log error

Comment: @Markjose If your still having issues, you can follow this simple tutorial =>  http://www.tizag.com/phpT/fileupload.php  ,It might help you

Comment: Ok, after reading the guide i changed both the form and the php script ( updated the first post) Still not uploading to the folder, however now i don't have any errors in log either !

Comment: @Markjose Please ask a new question in that regard.

Comment: Ok, new question posted.